# Solving a given Differential Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have tried quiet a lot of methods to solve the given ODE. $$xdy-(3y+x^5y^{1/3})dx = 0$$
Can anybody share any clue on solving this?

Comment: One way would be to rewrite the ODE as: $$y'=\frac{3y}{x}+x^4 y^{1/3}$$ This is a Bernoulli differential equation, which leads to the substitution $v=y^{2/3}$ to obtain a linear ODE.

Answer (score 2):

We have 
$$xy'=3y+x^5y^{1/3}.$$
Of course $y=0$ ia a solution.

Now let $y\ne 0$. Consider $y=u^3$, then $y'=3u^2u'$. Substitute:
$$3xu^2u'=3u^3+x^5u$$
or
$$u'=\frac{u}{x}+\frac{x^4}{3u}$$

Now suppose $u=vx$, so $u'=v+xv'$ and we have
$$v+xv'=v+\frac{x^3}{3v}$$
or $$xv'=\frac{x^3}{3v}$$
and you can separate now.

Comment: here y is a function of x therefore $y'$ implies $dy/dx$. does $u'$ imply $du/dx$ or $du/dy$, similarly for $v'$. Quite a basic question but little confused.

Comment: In fact we assume $y(x)=x\cdot u(x)$ and then by product rule: $$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{d(x\cdot u(x))}{dx}=\frac{dx}{dx}\cdot u(x)+x\frac{du(x)}{dx}$$

Answer (score 1):

$$xdy-(3y+x^5y^{1/3})dx = 0$$
Multiply by $x^2$ :
$$x^3dy-(3yx^2+x^7y^{1/3})dx = 0$$
Rearrange terms:
$$(x^3dy-3yx^2dx)-x^7y^{1/3}dx = 0$$
Rewrite it as:
$$d \left (\frac {y}{x^3} \right )-xy^{1/3}dx = 0$$
Multiply by $\frac {x}{y^{1/3}}$:
$$\left (\frac {x}{y^{1/3}} \right )d \left (\frac {y}{x^3} \right )-x^2dx = 0$$
Integrate.

Comment: @LutzLehmann you're right I changed it. I didn't say it's an integrating factor .

Comment: I do agree @LutzLehmann that it really brings confusion since it's not an integrating factor...

Comment: I think it's more clear now @LutzLehmann Thank you for your comments.

Answer (score 1):

We are given

$$xdy-(3y+x^5y^{1/3})dx = 0$$

Rearrange the differential equation to

$$y'-\frac{3y}{x}=x^4y^{1/3}\tag{1}$$

where $y'=dy/dx$. As suggested in the comments, this is a [Bernoulli differential equation](https://www.math24.net/bernoulli-equation/#example1) of the type

$$y'+a(x)y=b(x)y^m$$
To convert the Bernoulli equation into a linear equation we use the change of variable

$$z=y^{1−m}$$

As $m=1/3$, substitute

$$z=y^{2/3}, \quad z'=\frac{2}{3}y^{-1/3}y'=\frac{2}{3y^{1/3}}y'$$

and then multiply every term in $(1)$ by $$\frac{2}{3y^{1/3}}$$

so that $(1)$ becomes

$$\frac{2}{3y^{1/3}}y'-\frac{2y^{2/3}}{x}=\frac{2}{3}x^4\tag{2}$$

or

$$z'-\frac{2}{x}z=\frac{2}{3}x^4\tag{3}$$

which is a [linear first order differential equation](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/Linear.aspx) of the form

$$z' + P(x)z = Q(x)$$

therefore you can find the integrating factor and then the general solution for $z(x)$. You then need to make the substitution $y=z^{3/2}$ to obtain an implicit solution.